# ok to set custom property to express request?

Tags: express

I vaguely remember reading that it's ok to set custom properties on the express request object for per-request info (to be processed in later middleware for instance) .

Is this correct?

Comment: is actually the right way since the request object is specific to each request, you want to use it to pass information from one middleware to the other to the final response function

Comment: What I was trying to ask is whether express would somehow clean/sanitize the `req` or something, but I guess not. Thanks

Comment: no, express won't clean the req, because he uses it to pass information between middlewares, thats how sessions, and user auth work